# ASP .NET Core OAuth Authentication. The 'ClientSecret' option must be provided

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0

I use OAuth2 authentification with our custom auth server.

Неre is my Postman auth params that work fine

[image: Postman]

And here is my C# code that use OAuth extension [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth)

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(opt =>
    {
        opt.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    })
    .AddOAuth("oauth", opt =>
    {
        opt.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://custom.com/oauth/authorize";
        opt.TokenEndpoint = "https://custom.com/oauth/token";
        opt.ClientId = "C2561615-783D-47C7-A5DB-DD94FE51C005";
        opt.Scope.Add("full");
        opt.CallbackPath = "/token_grant";
        opt.UsePkce = true;
    });
```

It rises exception

```
System.ArgumentException: The 'ClientSecret' option must be provided. (Parameter 'ClientSecret')
```

But why? ClientSecret is`t nessasery parameter in Postman!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **AddOpenIDConnect** handler instead to get it to work. Using it, you can provide a secret.

The client id and **secret** is included in the request to the backend to request the tokens using the authorization code.

Sample code from [here](https://github.com/onelogin/openid-connect-dotnet-core-sample/blob/master/Startup.cs):

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options => {
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["oidc:clientid"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["oidc:clientsecret"];
                options.Authority = String.Format("https://{0}.onelogin.com/oidc/2", Configuration["oidc:region"]);

                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            }
        );
```